# jQuery - Storing tags using cookies or local Storage using jquerytagbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, cookies, local-storage

I'm trying to save the tags from jQuery TagBox Plugin (from geektantra.com/2011/05/jquery-tagbox-plugin/)

```
(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery.fn.tagBox = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
      separator: ',',
      className: 'tagBox',
      tagInputClassName: '',
      tagButtonClassName: '',
      tagButtonTitle: 'Add Tag',
      confirmRemoval: false,
      confirmRemovalText: 'Do you really want to remove the tag?',
      completeOnSeparator: true,
      completeOnBlur: false,
      readonly: false,
      enableDropdown: false,
      dropdownSource: function() {},
      dropdownOptionsAttribute: "title",
      removeTagText: "X",
      maxTags: -1,
      maxTagsErr: function(max_tags) { alert("A maximum of "+max_tags+" tags can be added!"); },
      beforeTagAdd: function(tag_to_add) {},
      afterTagAdd: function(added_tag) {}
    } 
    if (options) {
      options = jQuery.extend(defaults, options);
    } else {
      options = defaults;
    }
    options.tagInputClassName = ( options.tagInputClassName != '' ) ? options.tagInputClassName + ' ' : '';
    options.tagButtonClassName = ( options.tagButtonClassName != '' ) ? options.tagButtonClassName + ' ' : '';
//  Hide Element
    var $elements = this;
    if($elements.length < 1) return;
    $elements.each(function(){
      var uuid = Math.round( Math.random()*0x10000 ).toString(16) + Math.round( Math.random()*0x10000 ).toString(16);
      var $element = jQuery(this);
      $element.hide();
      try {
        var options_from_attribute = jQuery.parseJSON($element.attr(options.dropdownOptionsAttribute));
        options = jQuery.extend(options_from_attribute, options);
      } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      if($element.is(":disabled")) 
        options.readonly = true;
      if( (jQuery.isArray($element)) && $element[0].hasAttribute("readonly") )
        options.readonly = true
  //  Create DOM Elements
      if( (options.enableDropdown) && options.dropdownSource() != null ) {
        if(options.dropdownSource().jquery) {
          var $tag_input_elem = (options.readonly) ? '' : options.dropdownSource();
          $tag_input_elem.attr("id", options.className+'-input-'+uuid);
          $tag_input_elem.addClass(options.className+'-input');
        } else {
          var tag_dropdown_items_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(options.dropdownSource());
          var tag_dropdown_options = new Array('<option value=""></option>');
          jQuery.each(tag_dropdown_items_obj, function(i, v){
            if((jQuery.isArray(v)) && v.length == 2 ) {
              tag_dropdown_options.push( '<option value="'+v[0]+'">'+v[1]+'</option>' );
            } else if ( !jQuery.isArray(v) ) {
              tag_dropdown_options.push( '<option value="'+i+'">'+v+'</option>' );
            }
          });
          var tag_dropdown = '<select class="'+options.tagInputClassName+' '+options.className+'-input" id="'+options.className+'-input-'+uuid+'">'+tag_dropdown_options.join("")+'</select>';
          var $tag_input_elem = (options.readonly) ? '' : jQuery(tag_dropdown);
        }
      } else {
        var $tag_input_elem = (options.readonly) ? '' : jQuery('<input type="text" class="'+options.tagInputClassName+' '+options.className+'-input" value="" id="'+options.className+'-input-'+uuid+'" />');
      }
      var $tag_add_elem = (options.readonly) ? '' : jQuery('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="'+options.tagButtonClassName+''+options.className+'-add-tag" id="'+options.className+'-add-tag-'+uuid+'">'+options.tagButtonTitle+'</a>');
      var $tag_list_elem = jQuery('<span class="'+options.className+'-list" id="'+options.className+'-list-'+uuid+'"></span>');
      var $tagBox = jQuery('<span class="'+options.className+'-container"></span>').append($tag_input_elem).append($tag_add_elem).append($tag_list_elem);
      $element.before($tagBox);
      $element.addClass("jQTagBox");
      $element.unbind('reloadTagBox');
      $element.bind('reloadTagBox', function(){
        $tagBox.remove();
        $element.tagBox(options);
      });     
  //  Generate Tags List from Input item
      generate_tags_list( get_current_tags_list() );
      if(!options.readonly) {
        $tag_add_elem.click(function() {
          var selected_tag = $tag_input_elem.val();
          options.beforeTagAdd(selected_tag);
          add_tag(selected_tag);
          if($tag_input_elem.is("select")) {
            $tag_input_elem.find('option[value="'+selected_tag+'"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
          }
          $tag_input_elem.val('');
          options.afterTagAdd(selected_tag);
        });
        $tag_input_elem.keypress(function(e) {
          var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
          var this_val = jQuery(this).val();
          if(code==13 || (code == options.separator.charCodeAt(0) && options.completeOnSeparator) ) {
            $tag_add_elem.trigger("click");
            return false;
          }
        });
        if( options.completeOnBlur ) {
          $tag_input_elem.blur(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).val() != "")
              $tag_add_elem.trigger("click");
          });
        }
        jQuery('.'+options.className+'-remove-'+uuid).live( "click", function () {
          if(options.confirmRemoval) {
            var c = confirm(options.confirmRemovalText);
            if(!c) return false;
          }
          var tag_item = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
          if($tag_input_elem.is("select")) {
            $tag_input_elem.find('option[value="'+tag_item+'"]').removeAttr("disabled");
          }
          $tag_input_elem.val('');
          remove_tag(tag_item);
        });
      }
  //  Methods
      function separator_encountered(val) {
        return (val.indexOf( options.separator ) != "-1") ? true : false;
      }
      function get_current_tags_list() {
        var tags_list = $element.val().split(options.separator);
        tags_list = jQuery.map(tags_list, function (item) { return jQuery.trim(item); });
        return tags_list;
      }
      function generate_tags_list(tags_list) {
        var tags_list = jQuery.unique( tags_list.sort() ).sort();
        $tag_list_elem.html('');
        jQuery.each(tags_list, function(key, val) {
          if(val != "") {
            var remove_tag_link = (options.readonly) ? '' : '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="'+options.className+'-remove '+options.className+'-remove-'+uuid+'" title="Remove Tag" rel="'+val+'">'+options.removeTagText+'</a>';
            if((options.enableDropdown) && jQuery('#'+options.className+'-input-'+uuid).find("option").length > 0) {
              var display_val = jQuery('#'+options.className+'-input-'+uuid).find("option[value='"+val+"']").text();
            } else {
              var display_val = val;
            }
            $tag_list_elem.append('<span class="'+options.className+'-item"><span class="'+options.className+'-bullet">&bull;</span><span class="'+options.className+'-item-content">'+remove_tag_link+''+display_val+'</span></span>');                        
          }
        });
        $element.val(tags_list.join(options.separator));
      }
      function add_tag(new_tag_items) {
        var tags_list = get_current_tags_list();
        new_tag_items = new_tag_items.split(options.separator);
        new_tag_items = jQuery.map(new_tag_items, function (item) { return jQuery.trim(item); });
        tags_list = tags_list.concat(new_tag_items);
        tags_list = jQuery.map( tags_list, function(item) { if(item != "") return item } );
        if( tags_list.length > options.maxTags && options.maxTags != -1 ) {
          options.maxTagsErr(options.maxTags);
          return;
        }
        generate_tags_list(tags_list);
      }
      function remove_tag(old_tag_items) {
        var tags_list = get_current_tags_list();
        old_tag_items = old_tag_items.split(options.separator);
        old_tag_items = jQuery.map(old_tag_items, function (item) { return jQuery.trim(item); });
        jQuery.each( old_tag_items, function(key, val) {            
          tags_list = jQuery.grep(tags_list, function(value) { return value != val; })  
        });
        generate_tags_list(tags_list);
      }
    });
  } 
})(jQuery);
```

What I want to do is save the new tags using cookies with jquerycooie.js or using localStorage, but after this:

```
<div class="row">
      <label for="jquery-tagbox-text">Text TagBox (Comma Separated)</label>
      <input id="jquery-tagbox-text" type="text" />
</div>
```

if I add
$.cookie('thetags', 'tags');

and than refresh the page nothing is saved. Any idea or help?

Comment: Can you post "your" javascript instead of that of the plugin.

$.cookie('thetags', 'tags'); will store a cookie named "thetags" which contains the string "tags". Not super exciting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to use the afterTagAdd callback and (adding) a afterTagRemove callback.

```
afterTagAdd: function() {
   $.cookie('tags', this.get_current_tags_list().join(','));
   added_tag();
}

afterTagRemove: function() {
   $.cookie('tags', this.get_current_tags_list().join(','));
}
```

When you load the page, you need to add logic to add all of the cookie-cached values to the tags.

```
tagBox.add_tag($.cookie('tags'));
```

All of this is assuming that the separator you passed to TagBox is `','`.